# Convert SQL to EF Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM   Warehouse.WorkItems wi
WHERE  wi.TaskId = (SELECT TaskId
                    FROM   Warehouse.WorkItems
                    WHERE  WorkItemId = @WorkItemId)
  AND  wi.IsComplete = 0;
```

And since we are using EF, I'd like to be able to use the Linq functionality to generate this query. (I know that I can give it a string query like this, but I would like to use EF+Linq to generate the query for me, for refactoring reasons.)

I really don't need to know the results of the query. I just need to know if there are any results. (The use of an `Any()` would be perfect, but I can't get the write code for it.)

So... Basically, how do I write that SQL query as a LINQ query?

Edit: Table Structure

```
WorkItemId - int - Primary Key
TaskId - int - Foreign Key on Warehouse.Tasks
IsComplete - bool
JobId - int 
UserName - string
ReportName - string
ReportCriteria - string
ReportId - int - Foreign Key on Warehouse.Reports
CreatedTime - DateTime
```

Comment: https://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: @adaam Already have it. Thanks for the helpful comment soliciting a well known product.

Comment: Do you have a navigation property on the TaskId? Meaning is there a foreign key relationship there? If so, what is it called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct translation could be something like this

```
var result = db.WorkItems.Any(wi =>
    !wi.IsComplete && wi.TaskId == db.WorkItems
        .Where(x => x.WorkItemId == workItemId)
        .Select(x => x.TaskId)
        .FirstOrDefault()));
```

Taking into account the fact that SQL `=(subquery)`, `IN (subquery)` and `EXISTS(subquery)` in nowadays modern databases are handled identically, you can try this instead

```
var result = db.WorkItems.Any(wi =>
    !wi.IsComplete && db.WorkItems.Any(x => x.WorkItemId == workItemId
        && x.TaskId == wi.TaskId));
```

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not going to lie. I don't quite understand how that query works, but it produces really similar SQL to my answers. But it works, so I'm intrigued. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that I just needed to approach the problem from a different angle.

I came up with about three solutions with varying Linq syntaxes:

Full method chain:

```
var q1 = Warehouse.WorkItems
                  .Where(workItem => workItem.TaskId == (from wis in Warehouse.WorkItems
                                                           where wis.WorkItemId == workItemId
                                                           select wis.TaskId).First())
                  .Any(workItem => !workItem.IsComplete);
```

Mixed query + method chain:

```
var q2 = Warehouse.WorkItems
                  .Where(workItem => workItem.TaskId == Warehouse.WorkItems
                                                                 .Where(wis => wis.WorkItemId == workItemId)
                                                                 .Select(wis => wis.TaskId)
                                                                 .First())
                  .Any(workItem => !workItem.IsComplete);
```

Full query:

```
var q3 = (from wi in Warehouse.WorkItems
          where wi.TaskId == (from swi in Warehouse.WorkItems
                              where swi.WorkItemId == workItemId
                              select swi.TaskId).First()
          where !wi.IsComplete
          select 1).Any();
```

The only problems with this is that it comes up with some *really* jacked up SQL:

```
SELECT 
    (CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(
            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
            FROM [Warehouse].[WorkItems] AS [t0]
            WHERE (NOT ([t0].[IsComplete] = 1)) AND ([t0].[TaskId] = ((
                SELECT TOP (1) [t1].[TaskId]
                FROM [Warehouse].[WorkItems] AS [t1]
                WHERE [t1].[WorkItemId] = @p0
                )))
            ) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
     END) AS [value]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Any() function like so:

```
var result = Warehouse.WorkItems.Any(x => x.WorkItemId != null);
```

In short, you pass in your condition, which in this case is checking whether or not any of the items in your collection have an ID

The variable `result` will tell you whether or not all items in your collection have ID's.

Here's a helpful webpage to help you get started with LINQ: http://www.dotnetperls.com/linq

Comment: Thanks for your response. I like to think I'm fairly fluent in Linq, and I understand the use of `Any()`. It's the use of a subquery that I can't formulate.

Comment: Ah, apologies. I'm guessing this answer doesn't give you all the information you need then? Have you got a query semi-written already that you can share? :)

Answer (score 1):

Subquery in the original SQL was a useless one, thus not a good sample for Any() usage. It is simply:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   Warehouse.WorkItems wi
WHERE  WorkItemId = @WorkItemId
  AND  wi.IsComplete = 0;
```

It looks like, since the result would be 0 or 1 only, guessing the purpose and based on seeking how to write Any(), it may be written as:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT *
                           FROM   Warehouse.WorkItems wi
                           WHERE  WorkItemId = @WorkItemId AND
                                  wi.IsComplete = 0 ) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END;
```

Then it makes sense to use Any():

```
bool exists = db.WorkItems.Any( wi => wi.WorkItemId == workItemId & !wi.IsComplete );
```

EDIT: I misread the original query in a hurry, sorry. Here is an update on the Linq usage:

```
bool exists = db.WorkItems.Any( wi => 
   db.WorkItems
    .SingleOrDefault(wi.WorkItemId == workItemId).TaskId == wi.TaskId
  && !wi.IsComplete );
```

If the count was needed as in the original SQL:

```
var count = db.WorkItems.Count( wi => 
   db.WorkItems
    .SingleOrDefault(wi.WorkItemId == workItemId).TaskId == wi.TaskId
  && !wi.IsComplete );
```

Sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: WorkItemId is a unique value. (See my table definition in the question.) The original intention of the query was to reverse-acquire the `TaskId` of a `WorkItem` and see if other `WorkItem`s, that have the same `TaskId` as the original, are also complete.

Comment: I stand corrected, you are right. I shouldn't reply just before leaving work :) I will edit my answer soon, sorry.